# open PDF file from cross domain

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I would like to open PDF file in a new window on the browser from java script.

But i can't use `window.open`  because the file located on cross domain.
I tried do it via controller by `process.Start()` function, and nothing happened

```
 var p = new Process();
     p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(url);
     p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(url);
     p.Start();
```

(because of my chrome version?)
does anyone have good idea for me??
Thanks a lot!

Comment: why can't you use window.open()? Should work fine to open a file from another domain....

Comment: No, it doesn't....

Comment: Than you have a different issue if window.open does not open up a link to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like that:
I used Pekita idea (to put the file on my program directory),and then I could use window.open(), after closing the window - I could delete this file from my location. my Api controller:

```
 public string Get(string url,string fileNumber)
    {
        var urlInCurrDomain = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Documents", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url) +"-" + fileNumber + Path.GetExtension(url));
        if (File.Exists(urlInCurrDomain))
        {
            urlInCurrDomain = TomerUtils.AddSuffix(urlInCurrDomain, 1);
        }

        File.Copy(url, urlInCurrDomain);
        return Path.GetFileName(urlInCurrDomain);

    }

    public void Delete(string fileName)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Documents", fileName);
        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);
    }
```

my java script code:

```
function copyFileToDomain(url) {

$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "/Tomer/api/Mismachimapi?url=" + url + "&fileNumber=" + fileCounter,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (fileName) {
        showFileWindow(fileName);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        showError(xhr, error, "err")
    }
});
```

}
 opening window:

```
function showFileWindow(fileName) {
var wnd = window.open("Documents/" + fileName, "_blank", "x=y");
wnd.onbeforeunload = function () {
    deleteFile(fileName);
};
```

}

delete file:

```
function deleteFile(fileName) {

$.ajax({
    type: "Delete",
    url: "/Tomer/api/Mismachimapi?fileName=" + fileName,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        showError(xhr, error, "err")
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from JavaScript you just need to add an `HttpHandler` or a simple `WebForm` which will fetch the cross domain PDF file using `HttpClient` and write the file contents using `Response.WriteFile()` method.
And add call to that `httphandler` or `webform` page from JavaScript or using Anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the file on your program dirctory then you can use this code

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "YourPDF";
```

and then ou do this

```
var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        p.Start();
```

Comment: how can i move it? i have a lot of files in remote folder, can i copy the specific file to my program?

Comment: just put the file and program on the same directory @שולמיתשרשבסקי

Comment: Thanks. I used your idea. look at my answer.